# Python - mypy attribute error for `fractions` library attribute

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, python-3.11, python-fractions

I'm wondering if this is a simply [mypy config](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#example-pyproject-toml) issue, but I'm getting the following error when running mypy against some libraries, some of which use  [`fractions._RATIONAL_FORMAT`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/fractions.py#L57) module attribute, which happens to be a compiled regular expression (`re.Pattern`).

The mypy error actually says that it is not:

```bash
error: Module "fractions" has no attribute "_RATIONAL_FORMAT"  [attr-defined]
```

Clearly `_RATIONAL_FORMAT` is a `fractions` module attribute:

```py
>>> import fractions
>>> getattr(fractions, '_RATIONAL_FORMAT')
re.compile(r'\n    \A\s*                                 # optional whitespace at the start,\n    (?P<sign>[-+]?)                       # an optional sign, then\n    (?=\d|\.\d)                           # lookahead for digit or .digit\n    (?P<num>\d*|\d+(_\d+)*)               # numerator (possibly empty)\n    (?:                                   # followed by\n       (?:/(?P<denom>\d+(_\d+)*))?        # an optional denominator\n    |                                     # or\n       (?:\.(?P<decimal>d*|\d+(_\d+)*))?  # an optional fractional part\n       (?:E(?P<exp>[-+]?\d+(_\d+)*))?     # and optional exponent\n    )\n    \s*\Z                                 # and optional whitespace to finish\n',
           re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE|re.VERBOSE)
```

I saw some [relevant discussion](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12286) on this type of error in the mypy repo, but the solution proposed there does not work for me - it was to rewrite all imports as aliased imports (using `as`), and also setting the config. option `implicit_reexport` to `true` in the TOML.

My `[tool.mypy]` section in the project TOML looks like this:

```ini
[tool.mypy]
python_version = 3.12
mypy_path = "src"
namespace_packages = true
disallow_incomplete_defs = true
disallow_untyped_defs = true
disallow_untyped_decorators = true
exclude = "version.py"
explicit_package_bases = true
follow_imports = "silent"
ignore_missing_imports = true
implicit_reexport = true
```

I'm using `mypy` version 1.9.0 and Python 3.11.2.

Comment: Symbol existence for type checkers use .pyi stub files if they exist, before .py files. The symbol you’re looking for [doesn’t exist in the typing interface](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/fractions.pyi).

Comment: OK, I see. I don't suppose I could write my own stub file for my library in which the import occurs, in which the attribute is defined.

Comment: I don't understand why they have done that - surely all symbols should be present. Yes `_RATIONAL_FORMAT` is private, but it is usable and I need to use it.

Comment: I would just copy the runtime definition over into your project - no need to mess around with maintaining a separate stub file.

Comment: @srm it's a deliberate decision. Private details like underscore-prefixed variables are mostly excluded from stubs, as they do not belong to the public interface. "You can use" is not the same as "you should use". This private member is not documented, all undocumented members of stl modules are considered private and not intended for public use. While nothing stops you from doing that at runtime, it is bad for future compatibility - CPython team is allowed to remove that variable without notice even with minor bump. It may also not be present in other implementations.

Comment: Stubs file is basically a contract: you are supposed to use these and only these members, treating the rest as internal details.

Comment: Thanks @STerliakov. In that case the suggestion to create a (private) copy in my library might be an option.